# WSGI configuration with flask app

Tags: python, flask, service, uwsgi, wsgi

This is the first time I try to use Flash in front back a WSGI server. And I'm not an expert in python. The problem is :
When I launch my wsgi app, the wsgi.py is launched and launch my server.py.
The flash application is started.
But, it launch only the code in **main**.
So the code before the **main** of my server.py is not executed (exemple the conf reader in my exemple)

wsgi.py

```
from server import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_caching import Cache
import requests
import configparser 

app = Flask(__name__)
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
cache = Cache(app,config={'CACHE_TYPE': cacheType})

@cache.memoize(5000)
@app.route('/<api>/<type>')
def get_from_splunk(search_query):
    print(urlAPI)
    r = requests.post(urlAPI, data=search_query, auth=(userSplunk, passwordSplunk), verify=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     urlAPI = config['config']['urldev']
     app.run(debug=True, host= '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5
socket = project.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

I think i forgot something by I can't find what.

When I execute it python : python3.6 server.py. All is ok but with wsgi.py I have an error in execution. urlAPI is empty. I can't understand the entrypoint when it's executed from another file in python.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you are not creating flask app, atleast i'm not seeing this!

Comment: Your diagnosis must be incorrect; only the things **outside** of the `__main__` block are run when the file is imported.

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot : app = Flask(__name__)

Comment: @AdrienFERRARI please have your question edited and add the informtation needed.

Comment: I have edited it, I think it's better like this ... I think this just a concept that i didn't catch in python.

Comment: If I understand my app.run() from wsgi.py run my main function of server.py ? So how can I execute the code before my main (like the config instruction) ?